# Copy Legend Text in Splunk Dashboard

Tags: charts, panel, dashboard, splunk

I want to be able to copy the text from a legend (Circled Area Below) in a Splunk panel Chart. The legend has an associated drill down action. With or without drill down actions assigned, the chart panels do not allow one to copy the legend text by default. Is there a setting or html css format that would allow these items to be copied?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below a workaround with a Dashboard XML / SPL approach

The idea is to create a 'legend table' next to your chart

1/ In your Dashboard XML, copy/paste the following at the end

```
<row>
    <panel depends="$hidden$">
        <html>
            <style>
            #graph{
            width:90% !important;
          }
          #legend {
            width:10% !important;
          }
            </style>
        </html>
    </panel>
</row>
```

2/ In your Dashboard XML, add the id #graph to your chart panel

```
... <panel id="graph"> ...
```

3/ In your Dashboard UI, add a new 'legend panel' under the chart panel

Use the same search of your graph

At the end of the SPL query, add the following (assuming you'are using a timechart)

```
...
| transpose header_field=_time
| table column
```

4/ In your Dashboard UI, edit the 'legend panel' column
Display colors on values

5/ In your Dashboard XML, add the id #legend to your 'legend panel'

```
... <panel id="legend"> ...
```

Comment: If I add the above to my legend query, it nullifies the results. Should I remove any portion of the query to populate the legend panel with the same values I see in my chart? | datamodel NeworkTraffic Allowed search | search | eventstats count by dest_ip | where count < 100 | fields + dest_ip 
| timechart count by dest_ip useother=false | transpose header_field=_time  | table dest_ip

Comment: I want to ensure the list displayed in the Legend matches that which is shown in the graph.